# How to count number of selected answers on Qualtrics?

Tags: javascript, jquery, survey, qualtrics

I am new to Qualtrics and to JavaScript. I am using a "hot spot" question for particular reasons. I want to be able to count and display the number of hot spot regions the participant clicks. So I just need to run some simple JavaScript counting up the regions that have been clicked. I have tried numerous things with no success. Basically, I have created an embedded data element, call it "NumberofChoices" and I want to run some JavaScript on a question to count the number of choices and replace this embedded data element with the correct value.

Someone suggested jQuery to me, so I have tried something like

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function()
{

var Box1 = 0 
var Box2 = 0
var Box3 = 0
var Box1Clicked = 0
var Box2Clicked = 0
var Box3Clicked = 0


$j('input[name=Q1_1]').click( function(){
Box1 = Box1 + 1
Box1Clicked = Box1 % 2 == 1 
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData("Box1", temp)
})

$j('input[name=Q1_2]').click( function(){
Box2 = Box2 + 1
Box2Clicked = Box2 % 2 == 1
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData("Box2",temp)
})

$j('input[name=Q1_3]').click( function(){
Box3 = Box3 + 1
Box3Clicked = Box3 % 2 == 1
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData("Box3",temp)
})


$j('#NextButton').click(function() {
   var howManyClickedQ1 = Box1Clicked + Box2Clicked + Box3Clicked 
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData("NumberofChoices",howManyClickedQ1)
   })

});
```

This does not work. It always returns a value of 0, so I think the .click function isn't updating the variables. (I do have the \script and no conflict codes in the header, so that isn't the issue).

I have also tried something like

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function()
{
var Box1=0
this.questionclick = function(click,Q1_1){
Box1 = 1;
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData("NumberofChoices",Box1)
}
});
```

This DOES work, but only for one of the box elements. If I duplicate it for multiple and then try to sum them up, it only ever returns a value of 1. Plus, I would still need to add the modulo commands. I wasn't sure about the =function(event, element) for the above. Do I keep it as (event, element) or do I replace it with the actual click event and element?

If I do this, it does not work

```
this.questionclick = function(event,element){
    if (element=='Q5_1'){Box1 = 1;}
    else if (element=='Q5_2'){Box2=1;}
    else if (element=='Q5_3'){Box3=1;}
    else if (element=='Q5_4'){Box4=1;}
    else {Box1=0;}
howManyClickedQ1 = Box1 + Box2 + Box3 + Box4 + Box5 + Box6 + Box7;
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData("NumberofChoices",howManyClickedQ1);
}
```

Like I said, I've never used Qualtrics before and I've never used JavaScript, so I don't know how to troubleshoot this problem! I would appreciate any help I can get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You picked a really difficult task to start on. The issue is that the hotspot regions are in an svg, which the browser treats as an external object. Any script that refers to the svg must be within the svg.  Your script isn't, and there really isn't any way to add a script to the svg.

If you need to get a count of regions clicked, do it after the hotspot question using piped values from the hotspot question. You can do the parsing/calculations in a web service script or in a javascript attached to a subsequent question.

EDIT: Addition based on comments below.

Part of JavaScript to count regions checked in subsequent question:

```
var count = 0;
if("${q://QID1/ChoiceGroup/SelectedAnswers/11}" == "On") count++;  //region 1
if("${q://QID1/ChoiceGroup/SelectedAnswers/12}" == "On") count++;  //region 2
// etc...
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I started to think down this line after I asked the question.  Do you know whether Qualtrics runs JavaScript in questions that aren't displayed to subjects? For example, if the next question has a display condition attached, will the JavaScript run on that question and update the embedded data only if the display condition is met? Or will it run no matter what?

Comment: And do you happen to have a suggestion for how to count the boxes using piped text? The only piped text option I've found that works is to use Selected Choices for Answer (splits out the names of the variables which are turned "on"). But I will still need to count those. So I'm trying something like this, but no luck \\ var Q1boxes= "${q://QID5/ChoiceGroup/SelectedChoicesForAnswer/2}";
 var Q1boxes = parseInt(Q1boxes);
 var Q1boxesCount =Q1boxes.length; \\even though this isn't technically correct, I'll need to finagle it.

Comment: sorry... I'm not familiar with this interface!

Comment: JavaScript won't run if the question isn't displayed.  You can use JavaScript to hide the question, execute the rest of your code, then click the NextButton.  For your other question, I'll have to look at the hotspot piped values...I'll get back to you later.

Comment: Thank you so much @T.Gibbons! I really appreciate the help. I couldn't find great documentation on how Qualtrics stores and uses the hotspot variables, so I couldn't figure out good if statements, etc.

Comment: There are piped value for each region that have the text value of On or Off (e.g., Region 1 = ${q://QID1/ChoiceGroup/SelectedAnswers/11}).  If would use those in If statements.  See in edited answer above.

Comment: you are such a lifesaver. I implemented the above to run on the next button of a subsequent question and it works like a charm. I can't thank you enough!